# Hitting CPU Limit using BusinessHours

Tags: apex, cpulimit, businesshours

I am working on a method that adds business days using the BusinessHours class.

Here is the method I'm working on:

```
public static Date addBusinessDays(Date d, integer dayDifference, Id businessHoursId)
{
    if(d != null) {
        if(dayDifference > 0)
        {
            integer counter = dayDifference;
            for(integer i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
                if(!BusinessHours.isWithin(businessHoursId, (Datetime)d.addDays(i)))
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            return d.addDays(counter);
        }
        else
        {
            integer counter = dayDifference;
            if(d != null) {
                for(integer i = -1; i >= counter; i--)
                {
                    if(!BusinessHours.isWithin(businessHoursId, (Datetime)d.addDays(i))) {
                        counter--;
                    }
                }
                return d.addDays(counter);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm using the BusinessHours `isWithin` method inside the loop and that is causing a CPU limit exception. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to re-factor the method and move the `isWithin` method outside of the loop or some way to re-factor to avoid the CPU limit exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a Utility class like this

```
public with sharing class BusinessHoursServices
{
    //retrieves & assign the Organization level Business Hours to defaultBH 
    @testVisible static BusinessHours defaultBH
    {
        get
        {
            if (defaultBH == null)
                defaultBH = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true];
            return defaultBH;
        }
        private set;
    }

    public static Boolean isWithin()
    {
        return isWithin(Datetime.now());
    }

    public static Boolean isWithin(Datetime input)
    {        
        return BusinessHours.isWithin(defaultBH.Id, input);
    }

    public static  Datetime nextStartDate()
    {
        return nextStartDate(Datetime.now());
    }

    public static Datetime nextStartDate(Datetime input)
    {
        return BusinessHours.nextStartDate(defaultBH.Id, input);
    }

    public static Datetime getSLATimeByBusinessHour (DateTime input, Integer SLAhours)
    {        
        return BusinessHours.add(defaultBH.Id,input, SLAhours* 60 * 60 * 1000L);
    }

}
```

and call `getSLATimeByBusinessHour` with appropriate parameters.

For more information refer my blog post [Example of BusinessHours calculation](http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/01/example-of-businesshours-calculation.html)